# How to display a tree of objects in a JTree?

Tags: swing, model, jtree

Imagine a collection of objects such as World, Country, Region and City. World contains a list of Country objects, Country contains a list of Region objects etc.

I would like to represent this structure in a JTree and be able to add, remove and move objects around the tree.

Can I easily create a TableModel from this structure? World would be the root object and I would need to perform some object-specific rendering.

Any one know of an appropriate tutorial that goes beyond building a tree from simple text nodes?

Comment: Edited title; pleased revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You might start with the examples mentioned in [*How to Use Trees*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). You may need profile your code if the intended number of leaf nodes is large. You may want to consider a map as an alternate interface for the uppermost levels. See also the three-part series of articles starting with [*Creating TreeTables in Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/).

Addendum: Part three in the series cited includes an example `TreeTableModelAdapter`.

```
$ ls -1 src/bookmarks/
AbstractTreeTableModel.java
Bookmarks.java
BookmarksModel.java
DynamicTreeTableModel.java
JTreeTable.java
TreeTableExample3.java
TreeTableModel.java
TreeTableModelAdapter.java
```

Comment: I looked at those examples already. I know how to build up a tree by adding texts to nodes etc. That is not the problem. 

In my question I asked how to use an existing model in a tree **with the least effort** (why did you edit that out?) How can I update model and tree? Do I need to add notification to my model or can I add some kind of wrapper to it?

Comment: @paul: Reading your revision to the original question, I have nothing better to offer than my answer's first link. The second link has an example of a `TreeTableModelAdapter`.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out. I had a look at the JFace TreeViewer today and got a bit more traction with that. It'll be interesting to compare...

Comment: @paul: It might be worth adding such links to your question for future reference. Sorry if I over-stepped on your title. Your requirements go beyond the simple _How to display a tree of objects in a JTree?_ Maybe append, _beyond basics_?